# How do I display a word diagonally in Java?

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program that accepts a word then displays the word diagonally. So far I've only gotten it to display vertically.

The scanner accepts "zip", then outputs:

```
z  
i  
p
```

How do i make it go like this:

```
z  
  i  
    p
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class exercise_4 
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter your words");

        String word = scan.nextLine();

        for (char ch: word.toCharArray())
        {
            System.out.println(ch);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you propose to get the spaces?

Comment: It's sad that there aren't any System.out.printf() answers.  I tried to add one, but the question's been closed.  Try `System.out.printf( "%1$" + (i++) + "c\n", ch );` with `int i = 1;` above your loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:-

```
   String s = "ZIP";
    String spaces = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        System.out.println(spaces + s.charAt(i));
        spaces += "  ";
    }
```

Comment: the word is not fixed. its not always going to be zip it will be what ever the user enters

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
String spaces = ""; // initialize spaces to blank first
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) { // loop till the length of word
            spaces = spaces + "  "; //
           // increment spaces variable 
           // for first iteration, spaces = ""
           // for second iteration, spaces = " "
           // for third iteration, spaces = "  "
           // for fourth iteration, spaces = "   " and so on

            System.out.println(spaces + word.charAt(i));
           // this will just print the spaces and the character of your word. 


        }
```

Comment: this method doesnt work

Comment: what is the problem you are facing with this? I got the output right

Comment: sorry it worked. please can you explain to me how it works

Comment: how does it know how to print each character at new line with spaces

Comment: `spaces = spaces + " "` does this thing as it is in the for loop. The spaces variable will have more and more spaces because of increment according to counter variable in for loop. So for i iterations, it will increment i times

Comment: im sorry please explain what each line does maybe if you just added comments telling me what each line did i would understand. sorry to bother you

Comment: @user2433900, I have added the necessary comments, If you still don't get it, we can chat :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your words");
    String word = scan.nextLine();
    String i = new String();
    for (char ch : word.toCharArray()) {
        System.out.println(i+ch);
        i=i+" ";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) from commons-lang:

```
int indent = 0;
for (final char c : "ZIP".toCharArray()) {
    System.out.println(StringUtils.repeat(" ", indent) + c);
    indent++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer a StringBuilder for concatenation.

```
String s = "ZIP";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
   System.out.println(sb.toString()+ s.charAt(i));
   spaces.append(" ");
}
```